# PHP, Mysql search query on first 100 character

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have this query to make a quick search on my database

```
$result = $apt->query("SELECT * FROM news where title like '%$searchfor%' order by item_id DESC limit 20");
```

I would like to include the first 100 character of "post" row in this search query as well as the title row. Sometimes I have some characters that people may search for are available within the first 100 character of "post" row.

Any Idea?
Thanks

Comment: That MySQL has a bunch of string functions is not really a secret, is it?

Comment: Look into the SUBSTR function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the whole `post` and `title` and truncate that in PHP

**SQL**

```
SELECT post, title 
FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$searchfor%' 
ORDER BY item_id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

**PHP**

```
function limit_words($words, $limit, $append = ' &hellip;') {
    $limit = $limit+1;
    $words = explode(' ', $words, $limit);
    array_pop($words);
    $words = implode(' ', $words) . $append;

    return $words;
}

// this actually will give you 100 words
echo limit_words($result->post, 100);

// this will give you 100 characters
echo substr($result->post, 0, 100);
```

There is one more way to do it straight in the SQL that might save some memory.

**SQL**

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(post, 0, 100) AS post, title
FROM news WHERE title LIKE '%$searchfor%' 
ORDER BY item_id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

If you want to search both the `title` and the `post` fields you'll need to add them to the WHERE clause:

**SQL**

```
SELECT post, title 
FROM news 
WHERE title LIKE '%searchfor%' AND post LIKE '%searchfor%'
ORDER BY item_id DESC 
LIMIT 20

### If you need to map search term in either post OR title ###

SELECT post, title 
FROM news 
WHERE title LIKE '%searchfor%' OR post LIKE '%searchfor%'
ORDER BY item_id DESC 
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer. I still have some problems getting the good results. The second way you provided looks very nice. To be specific don't I have to make the query like this?   WHERE title LIKE '%$searchfor%' or post LIKE '%$searchfor%'  . Thanks

Comment: If you want to search both title and post yes you need to add that to the WHERE clause but you might only need matches in one or the other which means you should use OR. I'll update my answer.